# Importing tags into AEM from a CSV file

Tags: tags, aem

Our client has a spreadsheet of about two thousand tags they want to start using on their AEM-based website.

I need a quick way to automatically import them as AEM tags.

I was thinking of writing a script to parse the document and issue a number of POST requests to AEM to create the content at `/etc/tags`

As an alterative, I considered uploading the CSV file to the repository and handling the creation of tags by means of a custom component or running a Groovy script in the AEM Groovy console.

Both solutions would require a lot of work and I'm a bit short in time. I also wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel. I don't think there's a way to do complete this task using OOTB functionality but is there any way to speed up the process?

Comment: It depends on how complex the CSV is, but writing a script (I usually directly write a SlingPostServlet) is rather easy and the TagManager API is rather straight forward. Trying to adapt or configure an existing tool or pre process the input data takes usually more time.

Comment: @Thomas it's not hard but it needs writing and testing. I'd rather use an existing solution that's verified to work. The _Tag Maker_ suggested by mleczey looks very promising. It already does import from CSV and I'd just need to transform my files a little with AWK. I've given it a quick test and it seems to match my expectations very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Tag Maker](http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/tag-maker.html) provided by ACS AEM Tools.

You can find it in *Tools > ACS AEM Tools > Tag Maker* after installing the AEM Tools package on your instance.

It allows you to import tag hierarchies from CSV files and has a number of pre-defined converter that infer tag names and titles.

Comment: Thanks, I tested this today and it works. I just had to transform my CSVs a little to match the supported format.